# how to sum a list of raster bricks

Tags: r, raster

I have a list of rasters and want to sum them up, however I am struggling to find a way to do it whilst preserving the layers. Below is an example showing two of the bricks in the list, but how to do it for all of them?

```
library(raster)

vals <- 1:5
many_bricks <- list()
for (v in vals){

b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))*v

nam <- as.character(v)

many_bricks[[nam]] <- b

}

v1 <- many_bricks[[1]]+many_bricks[[2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

We could `Reduce`

```
out <- Reduce(`+`, many_bricks)
```

-checking with manual addition

```
> out2 <- many_bricks[[1]]+many_bricks[[2]] + many_bricks[[3]]+many_bricks[[4]] + many_bricks[[5]]
> all.equal(out, out2)
[1] TRUE
```